# Why do monolithic kernels require more reboots?

Tags: kernel, computer-science

Many articles discussing the benefits and disadvantages of monolithic kernels mention that **"Rebooting the computer is often required"** [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)#Monolithic_kernels ].

None of these articles really say why reboots are required though.

Can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: The OP question is "Why would frequent rebooting be required for monolithic kernel driver development but not for a microkernel driver development".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoted statement is made in a paragraph that relates to code development and debugging, not to the end result. That is, frequent rebooting is required when developing a driver or architecture-specific component for a monolithic kernel because device probing and driver initialization code runs at boot time and because the drivers run in kernel-space where a serious bug (an "oops") requires a reboot. In comparison, in microkernel designs, much of the driver code runs in user-space where it can be restarted as easily as any other user-space thread, without the need to reboot. Up to this point, the author is stating what anyone with development experience in both types of kernel knows from personal experience. Linux kernel-space device driver debugging is a pain and does indeed require frequent rebooting.

However, the author then proceeds to state "When debugging is harder, and as difficulties become stronger, it becomes more likely that code will be 'buggier'". This statement is **not** about development and debugging. It is a conjecture regarding the end result of the development for which the author brings no supporting evidence. In practice, the risk of buggier code actually being released in a kernel such as Linux is mitigated by the extensive testing of the code using the community-based maintenance model and phased release cycles.

The author does not mention the recent trend to use user-space device drivers in monolithic kernels such as Linux. These drivers are split-mode drivers that move most of the driver logic into user-space tasks and leave only a small amount of code in kernel-space, typically to poll for I/O and do DMA transfers into buffers that are processed in the user-space portion of the driver. An example network driver using this approach is [DPDK](http://dpdk.org/). This type of driver has most of the advantages of microkernel drivers, both in the development and deployment phases, without the messaging system overhead of the microkernel design.